# Prove that $r(P^n) =P$ , P is prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

This question was left as an exercise in the class notes from which I am self studying and I need help

> Prove that $r(P^n)= P$ , where r(I) is radical of ideal I and P are prime ideals.

I am unable to prove either of P , $r(P^n)$ to be subset of other set.

$P^n\subseteq P$  implies that  $r(P^n) \subseteq r(P)$ and also I have proved earlier that $I \subseteq r(I)$ which implies that $P^n\subseteq r(P^n)$ and $P \subseteq r(P)$.

But these ideas are not sufficient to prove any of the sides.

So, can you please help me with that?

Comment: Actually, it is $P^n\subseteq P$, not the other way around. Multiplication always gives us a smaller ideal.

Comment: @Mark I got it. Do you mind giving some hints on how to proceed with this question.

Comment: Can someone please tell why this question is getting so many downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring with $I\subseteq R$ an ideal. Then $r(I^n)=r(I)$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$.

> Since $I^n\subset I$, then $r(I^n)\subset r(I)$. Let $x\in r(I)$, then exists $m\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ such that $x^m\in I$. Therefore we have $x^{mn}=(x^m)^n\in I^n$ with $mn\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$. Thus $r(I)\subset r(I^n)$.

Now suppose that $I=P$ is prime, from the above we have $r(P^n)=r(P)$. Let $x\in r(P)$, then exists $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ such that $x^n\in P$, since $P$ is prime, then $x\in P$. Which shows that $r(P^n)=P$.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "But these ideas are not sufficient to prove any of the sides. So, can you please help me with that?"

**Answer:** Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring with $I\subseteq R$ an ideal. The radical $r(I)$ is the set of elements $x\in R$ with $x^n\in I$ for some $n>0$. It follows that $I \subseteq r(I)$ is an ideal for any ideal $I \subseteq R$: Since $x:=x^1\in I$ it follows $I \subseteq r(I)$. Assume $P$ is a prime ideal and assume $x\in r(P)$. It follows $x^n \in P$ and since $P$ is prime it follows $x\in P$ and hence $r(P)=P$.

Answer (score 1):

$P^n$ is the ideal generated by the set $\{p_1\cdots p_n:p_1,...,p_n\in P\}$.

As $P$ is prime, for some $n\geq 1$, if $x^n\in P$, then $x\cdot x^{n-1}\in P$ so either $x\in P$ or $x^{n-1}\in P$. By induction, we get that $x\in P$. This argument shows that $x\in r(P)\implies x^n\in P\implies x\in P$, so $r(P)\subseteq P$. As we also know $P\subseteq r(P)$, this shows $P=r(P)$.

To show $r(P)=r(P^n)$, let $x\in r(P)$, so $x^n\in P$ for some $n\geq 1$. Then $x^{n^2}=x^n\cdots x^n\in P^n$, so $x\in r(P^n)$, so $r(P)\subseteq r(P^n)$. As we know $P^n\subseteq P$, we also know $r(P^n)\subseteq r(P)$. So we have $r(P)=r(P^n)$.

Summing up two results, we get $r(P^n)=P$.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, $P^n$ is the ideal generated by the set $\{p_1\cdots p_n:p_1,...,p_n\in P \}$. So $P\subseteq P^n$ is not true in general.

To show $P= r(P^n)$, a hint is to show that $r(P)=P$ for any prime ideal $P$.
Then, you can proceed to show that $r(P)=r(P^n)$, which then gives you $P=r(P)=r(P^n)$.

Comment: $P^n$ is not the set of all products of $n$ elements of $P$. It is the ideal generated by such products.

Comment: @mathlearner98 You should elaborate your answer.